# While applying etag on the server response, should we not send etag for the responses with status as 4xx or 5xx?

Tags: etag

I am applying `etag` for all the responses but want to know whether to apply etag for the responses with status 4xx or 5xx

Comment: Why do you want to apply the `ETag` to client or server error pages? The client/browser is not requesting error pages.

Answer (score 2):

The specification describes [When to Use Entity-Tags and Last-Modified Dates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.4):

> In 200 (OK) responses to GET or HEAD, an origin server SHOULD send an entity-tag validator...

So, no, there is no reason to send `ETags` for 4xx or 5xx responses. Those codes indicate that a valid response could not be generated; therefore, there is no representation that the `ETag` could meaningfully apply to.